# Sortable material ui table

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I try to implement mui custom table, with sortable and sorting solution, I'am new with material ui and react. How to handel this event. I've created the method, need to sorting by direction enum: 'asc', 'desc'. Where to set createSortHandler method. Advice best solution for that.

[Online VS Code IDE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-csuz3d)

```
 const columns = [
        {
            dataKey: 'deviceType',
            label:'Device Type',
        }, {
            dataKey: 'deviceID',
            label:'Device ID',
            sortable: true,
            // cellRenderer: ({item, dataKey}) =>
            //          <Button >Default</Button>,
        }, {
            dataKey: 'name',
            label: 'Name',
            sortable: true,
        },{
            dataKey: 'currentVersion',
            label: 'Current Version',
            sortable: true,
        },{
            dataKey: 'location',
            label: 'Location',
            sortable: true,
        },{
            dataKey: 'status',
            label: 'Status',
            sortable: true,
        },{
            dataKey: 'lastAliveMessage',
            label: 'Last alive message',
            sortable: true,
        }, {
            dataKey: 'action',
            label: 'Actions',
            cellRenderer: () => <MoreVertIcon />,
        }]

    const data = [
      { deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
      { deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
      { deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
      { deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
      { deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    ]

    const defaultCellRenderer = ({item, dataKey}) =>
        item[dataKey]

const createSortHandler = property => event => {
        this.props.onRequestSort(event, property)
    };

    const Table = ({data, columns, order, orderBy, className,children,...props}) =>
        // console.log(columns.map(({dataKey,label}) => dataKey))
        // console.log(data.map(item => columns.map(({dataKey, cellRenderer}) => defaultCellRenderer({item,dataKey}))))

        <MuiTable >
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow >
                    {columns.map(({dataKey, label}) =>
                        <TableCell compact>
                          <TableSortLabel active={orderBy = dataKey} direction={order}>
                            {label}
                          </TableSortLabel>
                        </TableCell>)}
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
            {data.map(item =>
                <TableRow hover>
                    {columns.map(({dataKey, cellRenderer}) =>
                        <TableCell compact>
                            {(cellRenderer || defaultCellRenderer)({item, dataKey})}
                        </TableCell>)}
                </TableRow>)}
            </TableBody>
        </MuiTable>


    class  EnhanceTable extends Component{
      state = {
            order: 'asc',
            orderBy: 'calories',
            selected: [],
            searchValue: '',

        };
        handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
            const orderBy = property
            let order = 'desc'

            if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
                order = 'asc'
            }

            const filterData = this.state.filterData.sort(
          (a, b) => order === 'desc' ? b[orderBy] > a[orderBy] : a[orderBy] > b[orderBy],
        )

            this.setState({ filterData, order, orderBy })
        };
      render() {
        const { order, orderBy, selected } = this.state
        return(
          <Paper style={{width: '100%'}}>
              <Table data={data} columns={columns} order={order} orderBy={orderBy} onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}/>
          </Paper>
        )
      }

    }
```

Comment: Where is onRequestSort called at within `Table`